# Dynamically creating div and element created add style

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dynamically creating div and element created add style

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute("id","div1");
document.body.appendChild(div);
//above simulation dynamic ajax loading

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('load','#div1',function () {
        console.log(12323);
        $(this).css({'color':'red'});
    });
});
```

It does not work; console is blank; color is not red; help me;

Comment: `$(document).on('load','#div1',function () {` <- that never happens, and doesn't do anything ?

Comment: Div is creating using jquery or through server side script

Answer (score 0):

No need of `load()`.

```js
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.setAttribute("id", "div1");
   document.body.appendChild(div);
    //above simulation dynamic ajax loading

   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#div1').css({
       'color': 'red',
       'width': '100px',
       'height': '100px',
       'background': 'yellow'
     });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

The jQuery `load()` method loads data from a server and puts the returned data into the selected element.

You have to use `ready()` for the onload event

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute("id", "div1");
document.body.appendChild(div);
//above simulation dynamic ajax loading

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(div).ready(function() {
    console.log(12323);
    $(div).css({
      'color': 'white',
      'background': 'red',
      'height': '200px',
      'width': '200px'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: actually,all of li'elements is from a server ,wait datas response ago, I want the first element's style color is red! your answer is run ok, but 'div'  variable handle is not catch.

Comment: i am sorry, my english is disaster, so i describ is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').append('<div id="div1">Hi</div>');
  $('#div1').css({'color':'red'});
  console.log('12323');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) way to achieve it would be:

```
function createElement(elem, attr, parent){
  "use strict";
  var dom = document,
  el = dom.createElement(elem);
  if(attr.id > ''){
    el.id = attr.id;
  } if(attr.class > ''){
    el.className += attr.class;
  }
  if (parent > '') {
    parent.appendChild(el);
  } else {
    dom.body.appendChild(el);
  }
}

var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
createElement("div", {id: "test1", class: "test2"}, div1);
```